# iOS Error loading your issues in Firebase Crashlytics dashboard

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, crashlytics

[Firebase Crashlytics dashboard error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8uhL.png)

In my Firebase Crashlytics console, I can not see my crash reports. It is saying Error loading.See the above picture for details.

**My Podfile:**

```
platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'myproject' do
# Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use 
dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!
pod 'DatePickerDialog'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.11.5'
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.1.0'
pod 'nanopb'
pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.11'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.10.7'

# Pods for myproject

    target 'myprojectTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
end

target 'myprojectUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
end

end
```

Comment: Have you followed all steps correctly as in the Crashlytics documentation?

Comment: Yes, I think. It shows Crash free statistics but not Crash report.

Comment: Was any crashes before or is it the first time you are expecting crash?

Comment: There was crash logs before.

Comment: Oh then it has got nothing to do with the setup I believe.

Answer (score 0):

I know this seems stupid but have you tried going to Firebase support?

Comment: Firebase support page suggests to ask the question in Stackoverflow in step 2. See details: [https://firebase.google.com/support/] Thanks

Comment: @khanbdse I have looked at all the documentation and it looks like you have nothing wrong there, I think this is a problem on Google's end... Maybe try restarting your browser or even your laptop. Otherwise, I am sorry I was not able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Mike from Firebase here. Please contact our support team via https://firebase.google.com/support/ and include any errors you see from Developers Tools -> Console.

Comment: This issue has been fixed automatically after couple of hour. I can see my crash logs now like before.

Comment: Hmm, very odd, but glad you're all set.

Comment: @MikeBonnell I am facing similar issue with my iOS app. i am filtering last 90 days crashlytics data which shows 92.49% crash free users but not a single crash is logged and it shows 0 crashes. please help to resolve such a major discrepancy. Thanks